# Can a command be used once per user?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I was making a (Advanced) Embed Creation Command. Basically whatever you type will be shown as an embed. Long story short, I told my friend to test it out for any bugs. First thing he tried was to run the exact same command without actually using it. What I mean by that? Well he just typed `/createembed` for about x amount of times. The bot started to respond in every call that was made and it basically ended up spamming:

[image]

I think now it is a bit easier to understand what I mean. Anyways any idea how can I stop that by telling the bot that a user can use this exact command only once per user?

```
@commands.command()
async def cad(self, ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel = None):
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel

    aPP = ctx.author.avatar_url

    if not channel:
        await ctx.channel.send(f"**{ctx.author}** | Waiting for an Advanced Embed Title. If you wish to cancel this action, just type `Cancel`.")
        title = await self.client.wait_for("message", check=check)

        if title.content.lower() == "cancel" or title.content.upper() == "Cancel":
            await ctx.channel.send(f'**{ctx.author}** | Action has been canceled.')
            return

        else:
            await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}** | Waiting for an Advanced Embed Description. If you wish to cancel this action, just type `Cancel`.")
            desc = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

            if desc.content.lower() == "cancel" or desc.content.upper() == "Cancel":
                await ctx.channel.send(f'**{ctx.author}** | Action has been canceled.')
                return
            
            else:
                await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}** | Waiting for an Advanced Embed Author Text. If you wish to skip this type `Skip` otherwise if you want to cancel this action, just type `Cancel`.")
                authortext = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

                if authortext.content.lower() == "cancel" or authortext.content.upper() == "Cancel":
                    await ctx.channel.send(f'**{ctx.author}** | Action has been canceled.')
                    return
```

It has like 500 more lines but it's basically the same thing with more returns etc.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you without any of your code?

Comment: I'm just asking if it is possible and how to make anything Like that. I will upload the code then. One second!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this decorator from discord.ext.commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.max_concurrency).

For example :

```
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.command()
@commands.max_concurrency(number=1, per=commands.BucketType.user, wait=False)
async def cad(self, ctx):
    #your command
```

Will allow your user to run the command once simultaneously.