# How to stop multiple of the same command from one user? (discord bots)

Tags: python, command, discord.py

I am running something similar to a guessing game where you are given boundaries and my bot will tell you if your guess is higher or lower. I'm wondering how I would stop the user from opening multiple games? (as in, it would overlap messages and get real ugly and I want to avoid that.) Here is my code:

```
             aliases=['gg', 'guessinggame'])
async def guessing_game(ctx, num):
    number = random.randint(0, int(num))
    await ctx.send("Game started!")
    num_of_tries = 0
    user = ctx.author.id
    await ctx.send('Take a guess.')
    while True:
        response = await bot.wait_for('message')
        currentsender = response.author.id
        if currentsender != user or currentsender == bot.user.id:
            continue
        # if not response.content.lower().startswith('b&'):
        #     continue
        if response.content == "stop bot pls":
            await ctx.send(f'Stopped game, {response.author.mention}')
            return
        if not response.content.isdigit():
            continue
        num_of_tries += 1
        guess = int(response.content)
        if guess < number:
            await ctx.send(f'My number is larger, {response.author.mention}.')
            await ctx.send('Take a guess.')
        elif guess > number:
            await ctx.send(f'My number is smaller, {response.author.mention}.')
            await ctx.send('Take a guess.')
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'Hey, {response.author.mention}, you got it! (with {num_of_tries} tries)')
            return
```

Comment: Hello, I will just redirect you to [a response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66440354/15314892) that I made few days ago! 

Hope this helps you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a command be used once per user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66439352/can-a-command-be-used-once-per-user)

Comment: Alright, it works, to a certain extent. It allows people to start one game in one server only. For some reason, when I tried to use it on different servers, it carried over, and when I issued the stop function in one server (the one without the active game) it sent the stopping message in the other server. Also, does this code work for multiple people because it says "too many people using this command" and since I have nobody to test it with, I don't know. Is there any way to make this server-specific?