# Discord.py: How would i stop a command from being called while in the middle of a user prompt for a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
....
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!c ', case_insensitive=True)
.......
@client.command()
async def YourName(ctx):
   await ctx.send('Enter name: ')
   msg = await client.wait_for("message")
```

If the user inputs: "!c YourName" when they are asked 'Enter name: ' how would i be able to stop the command from being called again and saving that input into msg?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You can simply add a `name` argument to the command and get the user's name that way.

Comment: Looks like a similar question, check the accepted answer [Can a command be used once per user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66439352/can-a-command-be-used-once-per-user)

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution i was looking for! My code im working on isnt the example that i gave above but it was the core problem i was having making commands on my discord bot. @Ceres